# using jTextField to search in database

Tags: java, sql, swing

I am trying to search data using jTextField and view in jTable I am using the following code but I get the following message.

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Comparisons between 'INTEGER' and 'VARCHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match, a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default collation  e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')

```
try{ 
String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PROCAT";
String uName = "zain";
String uPass = "zain";
con = DriverManager.getConnection(host,uName,uPass);
sql = con.createStatement( );
                sql=con.createStatement();      
                rs=sql.executeQuery("select * from DATASAV where  ID="+jTextField2.getText());

                                while (rs.next()) {


                  String Name = rs.getString("PROID");
                  String Protxt = rs.getString("PRODNAME");
                  String pro = rs.getString("PROPRICE");
                  String[] data = {Name, Protxt, pro};
                  tabMode.addRow(data);

                    jTextField1.setText(rs.getString(2));
                    jTextField3.setText(rs.getString(3));

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
            }
```

Comment: what type of datatype are you using for your ID field in database?

Comment: i was using Integer but i changed to varchar and i still get same message

Comment: try appending single quotes around jTextField2.getText().
Plus, i would advise u to use `PreparedStatement`s

Answer (score 1):

The method `getText()` called on `jTextField` Object will return a `String` 
I guess your database id is an `int` that is why you are getting the SQLSyntaxErrorException

The easiest way to solve it will be to parse the String into int

```
String valueAsString = jTextField2.getText();
try {
  int num = Integer.parseInt(valueAsString );
  sql=con.createStatement();      
  rs=sql.executeQuery("select * from DATASAV where  ID=" + num);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e){
   System.out.println("Invalide Number + " e.getMessage());
}
```

Notice, Make sure you use `Integer.parseInt()` inside a try catch block, it might throw `NumberFormatException`

Comment: thank Jacob i get the following error                                             Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "          1   "
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at n